# Getting the index column in groupby()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have been using `groupybe()` to see how many each employee has done projects. It works fine but I would like to extract the employee_id column too, but i can not use it:
[image]

when I do `n_project[0]` I get only the first value without the id. Any ideas on how do I fix that problem?

Comment: Does `df.iloc[0]` solve your problem?

Comment: you mean ```n_project.iloc[0]``` ? It does not work either.

Comment: Your goal is to get the id and the value and write this to one variable, right? Of wich type should the new variable be? tup = (n_project.index[0], n_project.iloc[0]) gives you a tuple with (id, value). Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.groupby()` function takes a column or columns and sets as the index of the output DataFrame by default. If that's not the desired output, try adding the `as_index = False` argument into the groupby function. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

```
n_project = df_projects.groupby('employee_id', as_index=False)['project_id'].count()
```